# Angular2 create model nested forms

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

i am trying to create nested forms but i am stuck in the second level and not sure how the addAttribute and removeAttribute will look like ?

```
export class ExportFormComponent implements OnInit {

    public exportForm: FormGroup;

    constructor( private formBuilder: FormBuilder ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.exportForm = this.formBuilder.group( {
            dataType: [''],
            items: this.formBuilder.array( [
                this.initItem(),
            ] )
        });
    }

    initItem() {
        return this.formBuilder.group( {
            exportExpression: [''],
            description: [''],
            updatable: [true],
            attributes: this.formBuilder.array( [
                this.initAttribute(),
            ] )
        });
    }

    initAttribute() {
        return this.formBuilder.group( {
            exportExpression: [''],
            localizedRawField: [''],
            localizable: [true],
        });
    }

    addItem() {
        const control = <FormArray>this.exportForm.controls['items'];
        control.push( this.initItem() );
    }

    removeItem( i: number ) {
        const control = <FormArray>this.exportForm.controls['items'];
        control.removeAt( i );
    }

    addAttribute() {

    }

    removeAttribute(  ) {

    }

    save( exportConfiguration: ExportConfiguration ) {
        console.log( exportConfiguration );
    }
}
```

My interface tree

```
export interface ExportConfiguration {
    dataType?: string,
    items?: Item[],
}

export interface Item {
    exportExpression?: string,
    description?: string,
    updatable?: boolean,
    attributes?: Attribute[],
}

export interface Attribute {
    exportExpression?: string,
    localizable?: boolean,
    localizedRawField?: string,
    rules?: TransformationRule[]
}

export interface TransformationRule {
    dataPathKey?: string,
    expressionCheck?: boolean,
    expression?: string,
}
```

EDIT

Okay so i used the demo posted as one of the answers but i get null in the following `( this.itemsCtrl.get( '${index}.attributes' ) as FormArray )`

```
addAttribute( index: number ) {
        ( this.itemsCtrl.get( '${index}.attributes' ) as FormArray ).push( this.initAttribute() );
    }
```

Comment: Can you describe the final shape of the tree of controls for your form, indicating which parts are dynamic?

Comment: @AngularFrance : I updated. Does it help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I prefer to create references in component to handle the controls, instead of calling `.controls` or `.get` all the time.

So, your `add`'s and `remove`'s *functions* will be cleaner as your *template*.

It could be like this:

```
exportForm: FormGroup;
dataTypeCtrl: FormControl;
itemsCtrl: FormArray;

constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.dataTypeCtrl = this.formBuilder.control('');
  this.itemsCtrl = this.formBuilder.array([this.initItem()]);

  this.exportForm = this.formBuilder.group( {
      dataType: this.dataTypeCtrl,
      items: this.itemsCtrl
  });
}

// ...

addItem() {
  this.itemsCtrl.push(this.initItem());
}

removeItem(i: number) {
  this.itemsCtrl.removeAt(i);
}

addAttribute(index: number) {
  this.itemsCtrl.get(`${index}.attributes`).push(this.initAttribute())
}

removeAttribute(itemIndex: number, attrIndex: number) {
  this.itemsCtrl.get(`${itemIndex}.attributes`).removeAt(attrIndex)
}
```

Then, in template you can access directly the `controls`, as below:

```
...
<div formArrayName="items" *ngFor="let itemCtrl of itemsCtrl.controls; let i = index">
  <div [formGroupName]="i">
    <button (click)="removeItem(i)">Remove item</button>
    <input type="text" formControlName="description">
    <!-- other inputs from items -->

    <button (click)="addAttribute(i)">Add attribute</button>

    <div formArrayName="attributes" *ngFor="let attributeCtrl of itemCtrl.get('attributes').controls; let j = index">
      <div [formGroupName]="j">
        <button (click)="removeAttribute(i, j)">Remove attribute</button>
        <input type="text" formControlName="exportExpression"
        <!-- other inputs from attributes -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

See <kbd>[**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/8yqPPa0ISODkZd3an85l)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you. What does it means this.formBuilder.control('')

Comment: @SaurabhKumar You're welcome :) `this.formBuilder.control('')` is a sugar(or not) syntax to `new FormControl('')`. I've edited the answer to include a demo, you can check all the *source* there.

Comment: Oh this is super cool . Awesome. Thanks a lot I am learning angular :)

Comment: Oh .. my editor says Property 'push' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'. Could you please tell me what should i do. Same for removeAt. itemsCtrl.get( '${index}.attributes' ).push...

Comment: @SaurabhKumar `(itemsCtrl.get(...) as FormArray).push`.. the same for removeAt.

Comment: Thank you. Error gone. If i have to go one more level how should my control look like ? Updated my tree

Comment: It's exactly the same way as `attributes`.

Comment: Okay figured it out. Marked as answe

Comment: i am getting Cannot read property 'push' of null for addAttribute( index: number )  :( . I can see index is 0

Comment: wel the demo works but in the demo we are not doing casting. I think the demo is with old version of angular

Comment: @SaurabhKumar Nope. The casting has nothing to do with this error. I've updated the plunker (you can see it on the same link) with the casting just to show that it works the same way. About the Angular version, the plunker is updated (it automatically catches the last version, you can see it inspecting the element: `<my-app ng-version="2.4.8">`.